# Usage of %line directive in NASM with dwarf debug format does not result in expected line numbers

Tags: x86-64, nasm, elf, dwarf

I'm compiling the following code with NASM (nasm -g -F dwarf -f elf64 test.asm && gcc -g3 test.o).

```
global main

section .text

main:

%line 1 test.txt
PUSH 1337

%line 2 test.txt
PUSH 1338

%line 3 test.txt
PUSH 1339
%line 8 test.txt
POP RAX
%line 9 test.txt
POP RAX
%line 10 test.txt
POP RAX

RET
```

I would expect this to add the lines 1, 2, 3, 8, 9 and 10 to the dwarf data, however when I explore the file (using DWARF explorer, readelf or own code) I instead get the following lines:

```
test.txt                                       2              0x1130 (PUSH 1337)
test.txt                                       3              0x1135 (PUSH 1338)
test.txt                                       4              0x113a (PUSH 1339)
test.txt                                       9              0x113f (POP RAX)
test.txt                                      10              0x1140 (POP RAX)
test.txt                                      11              0x1141 (POP RAX)
test.txt                                      13              0x1142 (RET)
```

Every line number is one higher than what I provided in the assembly and in addition there is an extra line #13 situated at the ret statement. Could anyone explain what is going on here, and what I should do to get the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PUSH 1337` is on the line *after* the line you made line 1.  So it seems `%line` sets the number of *this* line, and NASM's normal mechanism for counting line numbers continues to operate as normal.  (Unlike [GAS's deprecated `.line`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Line.html) which sets the line number of the *next* line.)

The `RET` is 2 lines after the last `POP RAX`, so that makes sense.

[According to the manual](https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.11.1), the full syntax includes an optional parameter to control line-number incrementing; apparently `mmm` defaults to 1:

```
%line nnn[+mmm] filename
```

So possibly (untested)

```
%line 1+0  test.txt
```

---

NASM `-g` is designed to make debug info *for the asm source itself*, not for the line numbers of some higher-level source file that was compiled to a `.asm` NASM file.  The manual says it's intended for use with a macro-preprocessor (other than NASM's built-in macros), where it would make sense to have source line numbers increment.

But if you want to hack up that functionality, if `+0` doesn't work, I guess you could keep resetting the `%line` before every instruction, with the same line number repeatedly for ones in a block that all came from the same higher-level source line.

And use the number before the one you want NASM to use.  So I guess use `%line 0 test.txt` if you want the instruction on the next line to be reported as line 1 of test.txt, because 0 is the number before 1.

(Assuming NASM supports using 0 as a line number, and rewinding the line number to have the same line twice.)

I don't know of NASM directives equivalent in design to GAS's [`.loc`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Loc.html) which *is* intended for generating debug info for a C or other high-level source which compiled to a `.s`.

Comment: Thank you. Using +0 does indeed give the correct line numbers as long as the line # is not 1. The first %line is not registered at all if the line number is 1. Regardless GAS with .loc seems like a better option so I will give that a shot instead.

Comment: @Sindre: GAS was designed as part of a toolchain, primarily to assemble compiler output (especially from GCC).  NASM was designed primarily for hand-written asm sources.  NASM generally has better / clearer warning and error messages (probably for that reason).